# Expected value non-parametric?

Tags: statistics, nonparametric-statistics

I have some non-parametric data and I would like to determine the expected value.  I can't find any guidance on this in my old stat books (I find formulas for the EV of various distributions, but nothing non-parametric).

Background:
I ran a Monte Carlo simulation on a model for a business decision. The simulation ran 329,000 iterations. I'm trying to determine the expected value of the output. The data is heavily left-skewed. I ran a distribution identification test in Minitab and no distribution was found to have a good fit (I assume because of the large sample size). Not sure where to go from here.

I need to identify the expected value to use for comparisons between different options, as well as for calculating the value of information.

Here is a screengrab from Minitab of the graphical summary, with P-P plots from Minitab distribution identification tests below.

[image: Minitab summary statistics]

[image: P-P plots 1]

[image: P-P plots 2]

Comment: Not following.  Why isn't the expected value just the average of your sampled data?  What other computation are you trying to do?

Comment: Well that's my question, I don't know if the expected value should be the mean, or something else (i.e. median).  I tried searching and I found [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2873272/what-is-the-expected-value-in-a-non-normal-distribution), but the answer was basically "it depends" - use what you think is more important, without further guidance.

Comment: Expected value means the mean, period.  Of course there are times when the median is a more useful measure.  For instance, the median is a lot less sensitive to outliers and that might be useful.  But it all depends on what you want to do.  Here, of course, it is easy to compute both (indeed, both are handed to you).

Comment: The expected value is a synonym for the mean

Comment: Note:  looking at the graph, I'd be tempted to try to model it as a lognormal distribution (shift it to get positive values).  Might be worth trying.

Comment: I had the same thought initially.  I just edited the question to add P-P plots from Minitab to show the fits are not great with anything.  I could remove outliers to get a better fit, but I don't really have a justification for doing so - they're all valid outputs from the simulation.

Comment: Well, if you want to minimize the effect of the outliers, using the median might be a good idea.  The mean  sometimes handles outliers very poorly.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing - the median is probably better to use in this situation.  If you want to write an answer that says "EV is synonymous to the mean" I would mark that as the answer, since that answers my original question.